# Parse error:syntaxerror,unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) for class-oembed.php

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

I got strange error suddenly and my website is down. Even i cant login to wordpress admin account ...

here is error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/Myid/public_html/Mywebsite/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 191

I logged in to my host account filemanager to edit file and only i found on line 191 is this :

**"* @param string $provider The URL"**

Please help how to fix this.

**Few line up coding as follows :**

```
// Fetch URL content
    if ( $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_safe_remote_get( $url ) ) ) {

        /**
         * Filter the link types that contain oEmbed provider URLs.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param array $format Array of oEmbed link types. Accepts 'application/json+oembed',
         *                      'text/xml+oembed', and 'application/xml+oembed' (incorrect,
         *                      used by at least Vimeo).
         */
        $linktypes = apply_filters( 'oembed_linktypes', array(
            'application/json+oembed' => 'json',
            'text/xml+oembed' => 'xml',
            'application/xml+oembed' => 'xml',
        ) );

        // Strip <body>
        $html = substr( $html, 0, stripos( $html, '</head>' ) );

        // Do a quick check
        $tagfound = false;
        foreach ( $linktypes as $linktype => $format ) {
            if ( stripos($html, $linktype) ) {
                $tagfound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $tagfound && preg_match_all( '/<link([^<>]+)>/i', $html, $links ) ) {
            foreach ( $links[1] as $link ) {
                $atts = shortcode_parse_atts( $link );

                if ( !empty($atts['type']) && !empty($linktypes[$atts['type']]) && !empty($atts['href']) ) {
                    $providers[$linktypes[$atts['type']]] = $atts['href'];

                    // Stop here if it's JSON (that's all we need)
                    if ( 'json' == $linktypes[$atts['type']] )
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // JSON is preferred to XML
    if ( !empty($providers['json']) )
        return $providers['json'];
    elseif ( !empty($providers['xml']) )
        return $providers['xml'];
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Connects to a oEmbed provider and returns the result.
 *
 * @param string $provider The URL
```

cant get a clue whats going wrong ..please let me know how to fix this.

thanks a lot

Comment: Get rid of that last brace at the end `}` any good IDE would have picked that up.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 `{` for 7 `}`, I'm pretty sure there is one too many after the break;

Comment: It's probably the last one then, I did not check the code to be honest, I thought you'd do that. Anyhow, you have one too many `}`
Just so we clear...you're not including this file somewhere else are you ?
Also, don't forget to close your comment block with `*/` on the last line

Comment: i did add another website yesterday and this is happening ...i got 3 wordpress websites on hosting .....under one public html ......

Comment: Please post you code on pastebin or something, we need to see the whole of it to be able to help here...
edit : I can only assume there is more based on your reply to Fred - ii

Comment: i tried to question ..cant edit. ....where is paste bin ...getting lots of errors...shall i post new question

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ for several pages/long code, im new to this website too to be honest...I did not even know there was a limit.
Also, can you edit your question with the new error you're getting, Thanks.

Comment: You've taken off too many `}` now, there are two too many `{`, one is obviously where it used to be, at the end, and there is an other one missing, let me check this, I'll get back to you.

Comment: You need to add one `}` to close your main class, and one `}` to close `function discover( $url ) {`
Try like this : http://pastebin.com/iLmfRB6n
I'm not too sure about that as i havent checked the whole code, but it should work now. Also, I have ended the php code with `?>`, i'm really not sure why it wasn't done...

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function _wp_oembed_get_object() in /home/populard/public_html/holidayadviser.net/wp-includes/media.php on line 1398

Comment: Yes well, thats what I was telling you earlier, this is a not a self driven file, there are other file where the file acts so even if the syntax is good, it may however give a different result than what it was coded for in the first place.
You haven't coded this, have you, can you not download the original version of the file, get them both in a repo on githuib and check the differences ?

Comment: I havent done any thing .......i just added another websites ...another theme on wordpress and thats it...realise today that this website doesnt work ....does this files comes with theme.....only problems is i cant even login to wordpress admin for this site....this all comes with themes which i purchased ......but i guess this is wordpress error .....where i can find this file in theme folder......

Comment: sorry i raised new question now ...as took back up through softculous and not cant restore it back ...it says could not find directory ...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how softculous works so i wont be able to help you with that. Do you not have any back up of your files ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last closing brace is the one that's causing the error `}`

The one right above `* Connects to a oEmbed provider and returns the result.`

```
// Fetch URL content
...
    // JSON is preferred to XML
    if ( !empty($providers['json']) )
        return $providers['json'];
    elseif ( !empty($providers['xml']) )
        return $providers['xml'];
    else
        return false;
}

^--- That ONE right there.

/**
 * Connects to a oEmbed provider and returns the result.
 *
 * @param string $provider The URL
```

### Rewrite

```
// Fetch URL content
    if ( $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_safe_remote_get( $url ) ) ) {

        /**
         * Filter the link types that contain oEmbed provider URLs.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param array $format Array of oEmbed link types. Accepts 'application/json+oembed',
         *                      'text/xml+oembed', and 'application/xml+oembed' (incorrect,
         *                      used by at least Vimeo).
         */
        $linktypes = apply_filters( 'oembed_linktypes', array(
            'application/json+oembed' => 'json',
            'text/xml+oembed' => 'xml',
            'application/xml+oembed' => 'xml',
        ) );

        // Strip <body>
        $html = substr( $html, 0, stripos( $html, '</head>' ) );

        // Do a quick check
        $tagfound = false;
        foreach ( $linktypes as $linktype => $format ) {
            if ( stripos($html, $linktype) ) {
                $tagfound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $tagfound && preg_match_all( '/<link([^<>]+)>/i', $html, $links ) ) {
            foreach ( $links[1] as $link ) {
                $atts = shortcode_parse_atts( $link );

                if ( !empty($atts['type']) && !empty($linktypes[$atts['type']]) && !empty($atts['href']) ) {
                    $providers[$linktypes[$atts['type']]] = $atts['href'];

                    // Stop here if it's JSON (that's all we need)
                    if ( 'json' == $linktypes[$atts['type']] )
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // JSON is preferred to XML
    if ( !empty($providers['json']) )
        return $providers['json'];
    elseif ( !empty($providers['xml']) )
        return $providers['xml'];
    else
        return false;

/**
 * Connects to a oEmbed provider and returns the result.
 *
 * @param string $provider The URL 
*/
```

Comment: Is there any tool which can fix this ....i dont know how it happened ..i even didnt touch this .......it suddenly happen ...i cant do any as cant login to wp admin now

Comment: If you're getting the same error, then the problem could very well lie elsewhere. `Parse error:syntaxerror,unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)` is caused by unmatched braces. @user3238090 --- The number of `{` must match number of `}`

Comment: here is whole coding of that file :

Comment: Also, as `bastienbot` said in a comment, `/**` needs to be closed. So if that is your entire code, you need to end it with a closing `*/` @user3238090

Comment: Your whole code should be placed in your question, not in a comment please. @user3238090

Comment: i tried to edit code on question but change that either ...oh god ....i did tried to close code with */ and new error for line 192 now....how to place whole code on post please

Comment: I don't know what I could do for you at this point. I wish I could be of further help, but without seeing the entire code, which I tend to think stands to `very large`, you'd need to find where the missing `{` or `}` are located. @user3238090

Comment: code error is coming up ...now where to post whole code. .this website is new and and i cant answer as well.....

Comment: Seems like that pastebin file has been removed @user3238090

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with your code, besides having the letters `php` at the end `?>php` @user3238090

Comment: What to do then my friend ? where is that file will be located in theme folder....i cant file in my wordpress theme.....i might replace that file while from theme folder ...if thats possible...or do i need to contact hosting provider .....

Comment: That I couldn't say for certain. I'm no professional at Wordpress. @user3238090

Answer (score 0):

i can resolve this error in my wordpress by checking error_log file in root folder of my WP

in the last line of this file you can seek and find the error (filename and line)

and if you have backup of your WP ftp files you can replace them with a correct version

so finally it may need to delete some plugins of needed